# Crystal Report Gives me a Different SQL Result

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting a different result in CR. I got the right result when I tried to run the query in SQL Server

here is the example of my situation

TB1

[image]

TB2

[image]

what I am trying to achieve is like this

[image]

BUT the CR's result is like this

[image]

here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM TB1 tb1 LEFT JOIN TB2 tb2 WHERE tb1.ControlNo='IDU 2005.0001' AND tb2.Type = 'Applicant'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be the SQL statement used in the Crystal report.

Are you using a Command as the data source in the report? If so, please show the command in your question.

If you are not using a Command, please show the table joins and the record selection formula.

Most likely, you are not using a Command and the record selection formula in the report design is simply wrong.